# The number of functions $f: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$ for which $f(X) \cap f(Y) = f(X \cap Y)$

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, products

> Let $A$ and $B$ two finite sets of natural numbers and by $\mathcal{P}(X)$ we denote the set of all subsets of a given set $X$. Find the number of functions $f: \mathcal{P}(A) \to \mathcal{P}(B)$, for which $f(X) \cap f(Y) = f(X \cap Y)$.

I think that I might associate each subset of $A$ with its product of elements, while considering, without loss of generality, that each of the elements are prime numbers.

This equivalence might be seen as the number of injections (from the identity consideration) between a set of $n$ prime numbers and the set of all possible products of these prime numbers, which are at most $2^n - 1$ elements. So, the number would be:
$$N = \prod_{i = 1}^n (2^n - i)$$

Is this a correct reasoning?

Comment: Do $A$ and $B$ have the same cardinality?

Comment: I suggest ignoring properties of the elements of  $A$ and $B$, and instead simply think of them as two finite sets of arbitrary objects. The conditions here have no dependence on them being natural numbers. The effort you have put into thinking about them as numbers is distracting you from what is actually important for this problem.

Comment: I have checked the first 3 cases, where |A| = |B| = n, with n = 1, 2, 3 and an interesting pattern emerged $ T_1 = 3, T_2 = 25, T_3 = 729 $ these seem to satisfy the recurrence relation $ T_{n+1} = (T_n+2)^2 $ but some more terms will need to be checked to start believing that

Comment: @Carlyle Interesting observation. However, $T_4=83521$ and $(T_3+2)^2=534361$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is for each element $b\in B$, consider the subsets of $A$ that are mapped by $f$ to sets that contain $b$, which are characterized by the smallest one among them.

---

Let $|A|=m$ and $\ |B|=n$.

Consider such a function $f$. For each element $b\in B$, there are two cases.

- $b\notin f(A)$.
  Then $b\notin f(X)$ for all $X$.
- $b\in f(A)$.
  Let $I_b$ be the intersection of all $X\subseteq A$ such that $b\in f(X)$.
  Applying $f(X) \cap f(Y) = f(X \cap Y)$ repeatedly, we see that $b\in f(I_b)$.
  Hence, $b\in f(X)$ iff $I_b\subseteq X$.
  There are $2^m$ possibilities for $I_b$ since $I_b$ can be any subset of $A$.

So for each element $b\in B$, there are $2^m+1$ possibilities for $f$.
Hence the number of all possible $f$'s is
$$(2^m+1)^n.$$

---

A different method was presented in [the first version of this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/4683405/1).

Answer (score 3):

Let $|A|=m$, $|B|=n$, and $A=\{a_1,\dots,a_m\}$.

Plainly, the number of functions $f:\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$ satisfying $f(X\cap Y)=f(X)\cap f(Y)$ is the same as the number of functions $\mathcal P(A)\to\mathcal P(B)$ satisfying $f(X\cup Y)=f(X)\cup f(Y)$, which is the same as the number of ways we can choose $f(\varnothing),f(\{a_1\}),\dots,f(\{a_m\})\in\mathcal P(B)$ so that $f(\{a_i\})\supseteq f(\varnothing)$ for all $i$, which is
$$\sum_{X\subseteq B}(2^{n-|X|})^m=\sum_{X\subset B}(2^{|X|})^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom nk2^{km}=(1+2^m)^n.$$

Comment: After taking dual, we can also continue in duality to [my answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4683405/580448). For each $b\in B$, either $b\in f(\emptyset)$ or there are $2^m$ possibilities for the union of all $X\subseteq A$ such that $b\notin f(X)$. Hence, the wanted number is $(1+2^m)^n$.

Comment: Oh, I see. So there is a nice bijection between the homomorphisms $(\mathcal P(A),\cup)\to(\mathcal P(B),\cup)$ and arbitrary maps $B→\mathcal P(A)∪{∞}$, so there is no need for the binomial identity. Nice.